# Problem compiling C program that interacts with MySql db

Tags: mysql, c, database, ubuntu-11.04

I have a problem compiling a program written in C which should interact with a MySql db.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

I type this:

```
gcc -o magazzino main_magazzino.c -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

and I get this error:

```
main_magazzino.c:4:25: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

`-L` and `-l` are only relevant in the linking phase, and the program already fails to compile.

Check that `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` exists. If you have installed the [header files](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) somewhere else (say `/opt/mysql/include`), add that location with `-I/opt/mysql/include`.

Comment: In the directory include I mean /usr/include there's no file called mysql.h. There are many files .h .Also in the include directory there's no mysql directory ...

Comment: @Margherita That means you haven't installed the MySQL libraries at all. Install the linked MySQL C connector (on debian/Ubuntu systems: `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`).

Answer (score 0):

you need to install mysql c connector. 
you can download from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
after downloading you can specify header include path using `-I` option.

Comment: I have just downloaded the file you suggested : mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-linux-glibc2.3-x86-32bit.tar.gz . Now how do I install it? thanks

Comment: just extract it . you will find include folder inside extracted folder.